# Inserting SQL recordset data in excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am comparing names in smaller sheet to names in bigger sheet. Bigger sheet may have multiple instances of a name, so I need to find the address and sum(wealth) and store it as a single record in smaller sheet. There are many columns.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A")

For Each cell In rng
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet3$].Address,SUM([Sheet3$].Wealth) FROM [Sheet3$] WHERE [Sheet3$].Name=cell.Value GROUP BY cell.Value"
// How to insert the name and sum(wealth) in to sheet1's columns now?
Next cell
```

Also I cannot execute the code as I don't know to insert so can anyone verify if the syntax is write?

Answer (score 0):

Meesha, an alternativa to an SQL query would be to use a `Pivot Table`, have you tried it ? it basically does the sum of equal names trick. then you can use the `vlookup` function to look it up on the other sheet.

I'm pretty familiar with SQL as well, but can you post the exception thrown by the query ?

Comment: I have written everything in VBA, so I dont want to use Pivot Table. Also the exception given is  " syntax error (missing operator) in query expression". Thanks.